# Run from command line ruby method with return value

Tags: ruby, bash, shell

I have a ruby code like this:

```
module MyClass
    def self.my_method?
        return false
    end
end
```

From command line I have to call that method and get the return value. But if I do

```
ruby -e "require './PATH/TO/THE/FILE/file.rb'; MyClass.my_method?"
```

I always get $? or exit code = 0.

How can I call ruby methods GETTING its return value ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Kernel#exit`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-exit):

```
ruby -e 'require "file.rb"; exit MyClass.my_method?'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a highly unusual way to call Ruby code, but if you do need to do it:

```
ruby -r ./file.rb -e 'exit(MyClass.my_method? ? 0 : -1)'
```

That converts a boolean response to something explicitly passed through to `exit` where you can collect it as an exit code. You can map your result to some kind of error code if necessary. I've just used -1 as an example here.